# how to download customer csv including shipping address in manage customers grid?

Tags: csv, shipping-address, magento-1.14, customer-grid

I have idea we can get including customer address from data flow profiles export customers.

but client  requirement is getting customer information including shipping address from customer grid.

**Note:** i dont want shipping address columns in grid.but i want columns only in csv.

can you give some over all idea to start this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend/rewrite the Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController class.

```
public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'customers.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_grid')
            ->getCsvFile();

        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
```

With you own action:

```
public function exportCsvAction() // Modified version
    {
        $fileName   = 'customers.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_modified_grid') // call to a new block class.
            ->getCsvFile();

        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
```

The extend the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid with your own :

and the in the protected function _prepareColumns() you can put the csv columns!